# How to connect Angular app with IP Camera

Tags: angular, camera, streaming

I have an angular 8 application. I need to stream video from ip camera to website.
How to do that without backend. I want connect directly to camera.  Is it possible ? If it is how to do it properly ?
Camera have **192.168.1.108** ip address. Configuration of it has its own web panel secure by password.

I tried rtsp but I don't know how to setup it properly, I also heard about WebRTC but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? I am also trying this. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.